# VisualSVN Server Manager: WMI access denied

Tags: visualsvn-server

I have VisualSVN Server 2.1.10 installed on Windows Server 2003 with Subversion authentication. I works fine however from some time when I open VisualSVN Server Manager locally I get error

> WMI access denied. Please check the credentials and server security
>   settings. Learn more about how to configure server security settings
>   to enable remote administration.

I work on domain administrator account on machine when SVN server is installed.